# Kubuntu installer is not detecting SSD

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, games, ssd

The SSD has Windows 10 on it. I've left some unpartitioned space for Ubuntu to install on. HDD is detected. I'd like to dual boot for gaming on Windows.

System is Dell Inspiron 7577

https://www.dell.com/pk/p/inspiron-15-7577-laptop/pd

Thank you!

Comment: Have you updated Dell's UEFI and SSDs firmware? Have you changed drive to AHCI from RAID? Have you turned off Windows fast start up? Similar model? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342359 Fast start up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions UEFI:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Dell G3 when getting it to dual boot kubuntu 18.04.

Check your BIOS setup and see how your SATA controller is set up. Mine was set to RAID and apparently ubuntu doesn't like that.

I followed the article below to switch my SATA controller from RAID to AHCI and after that the kubuntu installer could detect the SSD. I did not have to reinstall windows 10 but could now install kubuntu next to it.

http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

I'm far from a linux guru so YMMV but that fixed my problem and it sounds a lot like your problem :)